# Loop through the list which has queries to be executed and appended to dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to loop through each element in the list and run this query against the database and append the result in to the same dataframe (df). Could you please let me know how to achieve this.

PS : I am using spark scala for this.

```
List((select * from table1 where a=10 ) as rules, 
(select * from table1 where b=10) as rules, 
(select * from table1 where c=10 ) as rules)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you load data from the same table `table1`, you can simply use multiple conditions with or in where clause :

```
val df = spark.sql("select * from table1 where a=10 or b=10 or c=10")
```

If the queries are on different tables you can load into list of dataframes then union:

```
val queries = List(
"select * from table1 where a=10", 
"select * from table1 where b=10", 
"select * from table1 where c=10"
)

val  df = queries.map(spark.sql).reduce(_ unionAll _)
```